# superscript leaving space in the html email

Tags: html, css, outlook-2007

A superscript is causing additional space in my html email.

```
<sup style="vertical-align:baseline; bottom:0.4em; position:relative;">&reg;</sup>
```

Now this works fine for web pages. But for the html emails, the space still persists for the Outlook 2007 client on a mac.

Is there a work around?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will help, but Outlook has problems with absolute and relative positioning due to it using the Word HTML renderer. Try getting rid of the `position:relative;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superscripts often cause problems in spacing between lines. Is that what you mean? Usually the styling in your code helps against such issues. (I’m not sure whether you mean vertical or horizontal spacing.) In any case, removing the `sup` markup and the related styling should help. The registered sign ® is meant to be displayed more or less as a superscript-like glyph, so making it a superscript easily turns it small beyond legibility (and perhaps somewhat misplaced).